# Application doesn't work on 2.3.6 android

Tags: android

I've an application with an intent on an imageView like this

```
    ImageView Image= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Image);
    Image.setClickable(true);
    Image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View V) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(V.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
```

I've tried it on emulator and some phone and tablet with 4+ android and works but on a Galaxy mini 2 with 2.3.6 android version, clicking on the image nothing happen.
Maybe is for the ad banner?

In the manifest i got this

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Comment: did you get exception?

Comment: I don't have debug on that phone

Comment: connect your phone with usb to computer and debug your code, because this code that you put in here must be worked on all version

Comment: What's your logcat output? MenuBar --> Window --> Show view --> Other --> logcat

Comment: Why dont you change to: new Intent(this, MainActivity.class); ?

Comment: check if the MainActivity declared in the AndroidManifest.xml .

Comment: can't get the viewwidth after the first layout
This is what logcat says